# gl.getQueryParameter returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glGetQueryObjectuivEXT: unknown query id

Tags: javascript, performance, webgl, webgl2

I'm trying to use the `EXT_disjoint_timer_query_webgl2` extension in desktop Chrome (which was pretty recently [enabled back by default](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1230926)). All my calls to `getExtension` succeed (both `ext.TIMESTAMP_EXT` and `ext.QUERY_COUNTER_BITS_EXT` return non-zero numbers) and I'm trying to follow [this doc](https://registry.khronos.org/webgl/extensions/EXT_disjoint_timer_query_webgl2/) to implement my code.

If I run this code every frame:

```js
globalData.startQuery = gl.createQuery();
ext.queryCounterEXT(globalData.startQuery, ext.TIMESTAMP_EXT);
let available = gl.getQueryParameter(globalData.startQuery, gl.QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE);
gl.deleteQuery(globalData.startQuery);
// <rest of the frame code here>
```

... it works fine. However, if I run it this way every frame:

```js
// globalData.startQuery is null before first run.
if (globalData.startQuery) {
    let available = gl.getQueryParameter(globalData.startQuery, gl.QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE);
    gl.deleteQuery(globalData.startQuery);
}
globalData.startQuery = gl.createQuery();
ext.queryCounterEXT(globalData.startQuery, ext.TIMESTAMP_EXT);
// <rest of the frame code here>
```

... which basically starts a query and checks it in the next frame before creating a new query, I've got this warning printed to the console in every frame:

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glGetQueryObjectuivEXT: unknown query id
```

This makes me believe that some code run during the rest of the frame is invalidating the queries somehow. However, this is the only place in the code where I'm using queries. Can queries be invalidated by some other GL code? Can `requestAnimationFrame` somehow invalidate the queries? Or maybe someone has any idea what could cause this issue – I'd be very thankful for any help or hints.

## EDIT

I was able to reproduce this error on a small code snippet (here is [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7u3ko0tv/) - you have to open Browser console to see the errors):

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
let gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
let ext = gl.getExtension('EXT_disjoint_timer_query_webgl2');

let startQuery = null

function onFrame() {
    if (startQuery) {
        let available = gl.getQueryParameter(startQuery, gl.QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE);
        //console.log(available)
        gl.deleteQuery(startQuery);
    }
    startQuery = gl.createQuery();
    ext.queryCounterEXT(startQuery, ext.TIMESTAMP_EXT);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame)
}

 window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame)
```

If instead of using `window.requestAnimationFrame` you call it as `for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) { onFrame() }` it does not report these warnings.

Also, it seems that when using the
there are no warnings emitted in analogous code ([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phu5qxar/1/)):

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
let gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
let ext = gl.getExtension('EXT_disjoint_timer_query_webgl2');

let startQuery = null

function onFrame() {
    if (startQuery) {
        let available = gl.getQueryParameter(startQuery, gl.QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE);
        //console.log(available)
        gl.deleteQuery(startQuery);
    }
    startQuery = gl.createQuery();
    gl.beginQuery(ext.TIME_ELAPSED_EXT, startQuery);
    gl.endQuery(ext.TIME_ELAPSED_EXT);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame)
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame)
```

Is it a bug in Chrome's implementation?

## EDIT 2

After seeing the above results, I started to believe this is a Chrome error, so I also [reported it here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1442398).